# Add required to select but it have already one value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'd like to have a requiered Select for the "Brand car", the attribute is added but the problem is that I have already one value "Choose the brand name"
how can I make this work? (for the HTML5 checking)

```js
$("#category").change(function() {
 var category = parseInt($("#category").val(), 10);
 
 switch (category){
  case 2: //car
   $("#car_part").show("slow"); 
   $("#brand_car").prop('required',true);
  }
  ....
 }
```

```html
<select name="category" id="category">
 <option value="0">Choose the catecory</option>
 <option value='2' id='cat2' > Cars </option>
 <option value='88'  id='cat88' > Trucks </option>
</select>

<select id="brand_car" name="brand_car">
 <option id="0">Choose the brand name</option>
 <option id="10" title="Audi">AUDI</option>
 <option id="16" title="BMW">BMW</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `how can I make this work`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add empty value to the select so it will be required if he chose "Choose the brand name"

the code will be like that:

```html
<select name="category" id="category">
 <option value="0">Choose the catecory</option>
 <option value='2' id='cat2' > Cars </option>
 <option value='88'  id='cat88' > Trucks </option>
</select>

<select id="brand_car" name="brand_car">
 
    <option value="" >Choose the brand name</option>
 <option id="10" title="Audi">AUDI</option>
 <option id="16" title="BMW">BMW</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this??

```js
  $("#category").change(function() {
     var category = parseInt($("#category").val(), 10);
     
     switch (category){
      case 2: //car
       $("#car_part").show("slow"); 
       $("#brand_car").prop('required',true);
                break;
      }
      
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="category" id="category">
     <option value="0">Choose the catecory</option>
     <option value='2' id='cat2' > Cars </option>
     <option value='88'  id='cat88' > Trucks </option>
    </select>

    <select id="brand_car" name="brand_car">
        <option selected="true" style="display:none;">Choose the brand name</option>
     <option id="10" title="Audi">AUDI</option>
     <option id="16" title="BMW">BMW</option>
    </select>


<!--If you want to display default text as option but want to disable it below will work-->

<select id="brand_car" name="brand_car">
        <option selected disabled>Choose the brand name</option>name</option>
 <option id="10" title="Audi">AUDI</option>
 <option id="16" title="BMW">BMW</option>
</select>
```